# Flutter error : Failure to access data inside a snapshot fetched from Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

Using Flutter 3.3.9, I fetch a record from my Firestore database using a Streambuilder.  I use the following code segment to do this:

```
              StreamBuilder<Object>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(userId)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Text('Loading...');
                  }
                  return Text(
                    snapshot.data!.doc['username'], // This line is marked as error bexcause "doc" is illegal.
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

The `snapshot.data!.doc['username']` gives the following error:

The getter 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

I verified that the 'Object' is of type "AsyncSnapshot" (=snapshot.runtimeType).  It looks like the only getters available for the snapshot.data are hashCode, runtimeType, toString(), and noSuchMethod(..).

I tried

```
snapshot.data!().doc['username'],
```

But this does not work either.  The error is "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked"

I was able to access the data without using the StreamBuilder.  The following works:

```
                  final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(userId);

                  docRef.get().then(
                    (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                      final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      print(data['username']);
                    },
                    onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
                  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two mistakes, in your piece of code, you should specify the type of the `AsyncSnapshot`, like this:

```
 StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>( // Specified type
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(userId)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>  snapshot) { //Specified type
    //...
```

now using `snapshot.data!`, it should be a `DocumentSnapshot` type, and as I see, that you're trying to get the data of that document so you need also to change this line:

```
  snapshot.data!.doc['username'],
```

to this:

```
(snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['username'],
```

now it will access the **username** field properly.

Comment: Well-articulated answer and it works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You define your StreamBuilder's type in wrong way, change it to this:

```
StreamBuilder<AsyncSnapshot>(

   ... 
)
```